# how to add struts action suffix automatically

Tags: java, struts2

I modified my `struts.xml` to use `.htm` for all my actions.

```
<package name="home" namespace="/secured" extends="default">
    <default-action-ref name="index" />

    <action name="index" class="homeAction" method="execute">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">home</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

I have a URL mapping of 
`http://someurl/someproject/secured/somesubgroup/actionname.htm`

However, if I call `http://someurl/someproject/secured` or `http://someurl/someproject/secured/somesubgroup`, I get a 404 error. If I add `.htm` to the URL, I get no problems.

I have defined a default action for the `/secured/somesubgroup` and `/secured` namespace in my hope that when I only call the URL above, the default action will be called.

Now, how do I add the `.htm` automatically? Or is there any workaround on this?

EDIT:

Here's the `struts.xml`.

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="htm" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />  
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>

    ...
</struts>
```

Comment: *I modified my struts.xml to use .htm for all my actions.* Where?

Comment: @AleksandrM I added the struts.xml on the post.

Comment: I've added an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to support actions without action suffix you must declare `struts.action.extension` constant like so:

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="htm,," />
```

Comment: But I ran into a problem. It works when I call the URL `http://localhost:8080/ivrbo/secured/` with a forward slash. But when I remove the forward slash `http://localhost:8080/ivrbo/secured`, the request end up to `index.jsp` of the webapp folder.

Comment: That is a completely different issue. Which is unrelated to your `htm` action suffix. You should ask different question.

Comment: Thanks. I already [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447049/calling-a-url-without-forward-slash-end-up-to-index-jsp-in-webapp-folder-struts2) the question.