# Calling a URL without forward slash end up to index.jsp in webapp folder struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

With some help of the people here, I've managed to get my project to call the default actions of the packages without the suffix `.htm`. However, the request end up to `index.jsp` inside the webapp folder if I call the URL without the forward slash.

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="htm,," />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />  
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>

    ...

    <package name="home" namespace="/secured" extends="default">
        <default-action-ref name="index" />

        <action name="index" class="homeAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">home</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Actions are executed if I call `http://someurl/someproject/secured/`, but calling the URL `http://someurl/someproject/secured` end up to the file `index.jsp`.

What to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `http://someurl/someproject/secured` url the `secured` is treated like action w/o suffix, because you have configured that actions can have empty suffix (which is also default btw). If you want that this url redirects to `/secured` namespace you can declare `secured` action with `redirectAction` result in package with empty or `/` namespace.

```
<package name="..." namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
  ...
  <action name="secured">
    <result type="redirectAction">
      <param name="actionName">index</param>
      <param name="namespace">/secured</param>
    </result>
  </action>
  ...
</package>
```